# Using a set of TImage to find a particular Image

Tags: image, delphi, set, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a VCL form with a left panel with 24 images (imA1 .. imA24) of TImage and a right panel with 30 images (image25 .. image53) of TImage. All images are 100 x 150.
These images may load pictures of 100 width, but of different height. The plan is to adapt the Image.Height and Image.Top in such a way that all pictures shown will be aligned by the bottom of the Timage frame.
As each image will be loading different pictures during run time, I need to store the Image.Top positions (I have 5 rows of pictures left and right).
The idea was to let this be done by a separate procedure. See code example.
The issue I am facing is that apparently my use of the 'set of' functionality is incorrect, or the use of the 'in' operator.
Anybody any suggestions? Thanks - Fred
(One alternative I found is to store the original top position in a separate record field for all images. Perhaps easier. But why does this use of 'set of' not work?)

```
Type
TForm1 = class(Tform)
  imA1    : TImage;  // and all the others to imA24
  image25 : TImage; // etc

Type
  TShow = record
    image : TImage;
    ...   : ..  // other records
  end;

var
  ShowLeft   : array[1..24] of TShow;
  ShowRight  : array[1..30] of Tshow;
  ...

{ main code }

procedure PositionPicture(Im : TImage);
var
 FirstRow = set of (imA1, imA2, imA3, imA4, imA5, image25, image26, image27, 
            image28, image29, image30);
 SecondRow = set of ( .. different ones ..);
 ..
 FifthRow = set of ( ... );
 T0 : integer; // should contain the image.top value for all first row images
 K,L : integer;
begin
  if Im in FirstRow then T0 := 40;   // THIS GOES WRONG !!!!  
                                     // 40 is for the first row
  K := im.Picture.Height;  // actual height of the picture now in Im
  L := 150 -K;  // all images have a default height of 150 pixels.
  Im.Top := Im.Top + L; // move down Im by L 
  Im.Height := K;   // Im.top is now no longer 40, so for a new picture we     
end;                // need to get the original position back

Procedure MainProgram;
begin
  ...
  PositionPicture(ShowLeft[3].image);  // e.g. 3 here
  ...
end;

Procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowLeft[1].image := imA1;
  ..
  ShowLeft[24].image := imA24; 
  // ... etc
end;
```

Comment: Take a look at [Structured Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Structured_Types) and scroll down to `Sets`. In general, you should at least once read [Delphi reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Delphi_Reference)

Comment: Tom, I did consult (various) sources including the one you referenced. Apparently my interpretation of those texts was / is wrong. I felt that already and that is why I approached this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of 'set of' is indeed incorrect. You are thinking more in mathematical definitions of sets, where a set can be made up on anything for elements. In Delphi set of specifically relates to enum type definitions, a bit like this

```
type
  TRow1Ref = (imA1, imA2, imA3, imA4, imA5, image25, image26, image27, 
        image28, image29, image30);

  FirstRow = set of TRow1Ref;
```

But this is not what you are trying to achieve. These are not images. imA1 will be given an internal value of 0, imA2 a value of 1 and so on., and any set you define will ultimately map to a byte or word etc. internally.

Instead you want to use some sort of array or collection, e.g.

```
var
  FirstRow : TObjectList<TImage>;
```

(There are many alternative ways of achieving this.)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `.align` property of all the `TImage` objects and set it to `alBottom`! This way they align themself on top of each other and you don't have to calculate the value of the `.Top` property for each one by yourself.

If you need some spacing between separate images you can set `.Margins.Bottom / .Top` to your needs and `.AlignWithMargins := true;`.

Maybe you need additional TPanels placed inside your "LeftPanel" and "RightPanel" to make this look properly, but your description of the form design is a litte bit vague, so this more of a guessing of mine...

Comment: Thanks, I tried align already, but that made all images move to the bottom and they stack on top of each other (in order of creation). A lot of panels will be needed to overcome this problem. It can be solved, but with more coding. I hoped for an 'elegant' solution I was not aware of. At least I now know that the 'set' option is not feasible.